# destroy cookies made by CURL login function ?

Tags: php, curl

i have a simple function i used to use to do login remotely to other websites using curl and php
this is the function

```
public function Curllogin($url,$data,$proxy,$proxystatus)
    {
        $login = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$this->SetCookieFile);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$this->SetCookieFile);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
            curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        }
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        ob_start(); // prevent any output
        return curl_exec ($login); // execute the curl command
        ob_end_clean(); // stop preventing output
        curl_close ($login);
        unset($login);
    }
```

its working with no problem to login
but there a small problem i found
lets say im log in to example.com and passed the username and password within the $data variable
it will login with no problem
but when changing the $data values using another username and password it's logging me in with the old username and password which used for last login
ignoring the new login information
i tried every thing like deleting the cookies.txt file and let the script re-create it
i even tried to clear my browser cached cookies
but it won't change it to use the new data
each time it use the first username and password which i used to login
is there any function to destroy the cookie made by the CURL or do i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `$this->SetCookieFile` to an empty file, possibly a random file in the temp directory. Your "real" browser's cookies don't have anything to do with this, cURL is managing cookies separately from that.

Comment: you mean i create another function setting $this->SetCookieFile to null and call this function each time i useed to logout ?

Comment: The `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` is a file where cURL stores any received cookies and takes cookies from to send back for any requests as necessary. The analogy of cleaning your browser's cookies is to empty that file.